# How to Move Back and Forth in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I know that pressing ctrl- will take us to the last place. What about if we want to move forward? Also where in the vb.net documentation is this mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (View.NavigateForward) it is the companion to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (View.NavigateBackword)

Microsoft released some PDF documents of the default KeyBindings for the various visual Studio Languages. It can be found at:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189

If that does'nt give you the information that you want you can view/edit the bindings by going to

Tools --> Customize. Then  Click on the Keyboard button. You should get a form looking like this. You can then look at what the current bindings are and customize them accordingly

[image]

Comment: Ahhh... Ctrl - go backward Ctrl Shift - go backward. Can you update your answer to make that complete. Thanks.

Comment: @JimThio ctrl shift - goes forward, what are you wanting me to change?